Put two plots into the same figure as subplots in Python
I am trying to add two plots into the same plot as subplots.
So far I tried :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
print(penguins['species'])

fig = plt.gcf()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=2, nrows=1, width_ratios=[1, 1])

#PLOT0
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]) 

g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, ax=ax0)  # Link the scatterplot to ax0
sns.boxplot(penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)

#PLOT1
# Add another plot to display the distribution of bill_length_mm values
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])  

# Plot the box plot of bill_length_mm values
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x='bill_length_mm', ax=ax1)

plt.show()

But I cannot manage to plot the PLOT0 in the left size in the ax0 fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])  and the the PLOT1 in the left size in the ax0 fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])  for some reason it does not work.
The last result should look like that :

In fact I think that the bay I add the boxplots in the margin of the scatter plot does not match the way I merge PLOT0 and PLOT1 together using fig.add_gridspec

An approach is to add_axes to g.figure. The dimensions passed as the rect parameter (tuple (left, bottom, width, height) are somewhat guesswork, but could probably be modified to match the left plot in terms of height and (a fraction of) width.
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)  # Link the scatterplot to ax0
sns.boxplot(penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)

#PLOT1
ax1 = g.figure.add_axes((1.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.75))  

# Plot the box plot of bill_length_mm values
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x='bill_length_mm', ax=ax1)

plt.show()

Output:


Hello thanks, but I really need to keep this way of plotting the data :                                      `fig = plt.gcf()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=2, nrows=1, width_ratios=[1, 1])
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])                                                                                             ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])`                                                                                                  Because in my real data I have a lot of subplots (8 plots) ...

Doesn't JointGrid create its own Figure? Not sure this will work.
